# iOS/iBeacon/Swift: How to keep the app running, after phone is restarted

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I understand any iBeacon application can continuously run in the background, if CLLocationManager is appropriate used; we were able to get it working based on the thread [iBeacon monitoring and ranging in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29984122/ibeacon-monitoring-and-ranging-in-background). From the thread [iBeacon Notification when the app is not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19127282/ibeacon-notification-when-the-app-is-not-running)   it appears when phone is restarted, we get the notifications from the underlying API if the app enters into the proximity/zone of the previously specified UUID (bcos iOS briefly invokes our app).

Based on above 2 threads, I am assuming we should be able make ranging happen continuously in my app. We want to be able to read RSSI always (even if user restarts phone or moves out/in of the zone).

How can I make ranging happen 24 by 7 (even if user restarts phone)? I know cellcontrol has done it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BvJJjBspP-4

Comment: Is there no beacon-in-range check/event fired when the phone first turns on?

Comment: Not Possible, According to my six sence