# Background Refresh App is not working sometimes

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon, background-fetch, background-application

I am using background capabilities in my app for which I have enabled it from capabilities. But sometimes it works well and most of the time it does not work.
- Background App Refresh is on From Setting of the device
- Device is not on the low power mode.

Please provide your suggestion that why it is not working sometime, and suddenly after that it start working

Thanks

Comment: Define "works well" and "does not work".  We need to know what the expected functionality is and how your app will respond to the background notifications.

Comment: I am using mini beacon SDK, which supports background mode. I have enabled Background Modes(location updates, uses bluetooth LE accessory, background fetch and remote notification). Work well on some devices. But on some devices it does not work. Will there be any kind of time constraints for Background App Refresh or any other constraint?

Comment: This question may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29984122/ibeacon-monitoring-and-ranging-in-background

Comment: Please show your code that uses the SDK to enable background updates and also show the code that "sometimes" gets called as expected but other times does not.